# Use Xamarin.Form UI library in Xamarin.IOS native

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Maybe this is a very simple question but I am stuck on this.

How can I use a library originally designed for Xamarin.Form UI in Xamarin.IOS native.

This is the library that I want to use in Xamarin.IOS, it seems to be very easy to use in Xamarin.Forms but I don't know how to use it in Xamarin.IOS

https://github.com/HorusSoftwareUY/Xamarin.Forms.Skeleton

Comment: Is the IOS part from Xamarin.Form project, but I don't see nothing useful on there, maybe I am missing something

Comment: I see what your are saying, I didnt notice the base formz probject.

Comment: @abelh Those project extensions/animations are Forms specific (they are using Forms animation APIs, etc..) and thus do not have a native iOS implementation.